# How to wait job until parent job get finished in multi threading in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, threadpool

I need one help in multi threading concept. I am not much aware of this concept. Can you please help me to do this?

Current Scenario:

```
Job            seq_num
A               1
B               1
C               2
D               2
```

In Above table you can see we categories the jobs based on dependency.seq_num 2 jobs dependent on seq_num-1 jobs. It means first seq_num 1 will trigger then after 2 will trigger. All the jobs in respective seq_num will run parallel manner.

```
Suppose Job A = 10 mins
        Job B = 15 mins
```

So total completion time of seq_num -1 is 15 mins.
After 15 mins. seq_num =2 will start.

Desirable Scenario:

```
Job       Job_Type      seq_num
A         independent    1
B         independent    1
C         A              2
D         B              2
```

In above table you can see Job C is dependent on Job A and D is dependent on B. In previous scenario seq_num was starting after completion of seq_num = 1. But in this scenario I want different approach.

```
Job A = 10 mins
Job B = 15 mins
```

Job C is dependent on A so after completion of Job A, immediately Job C will start. It should not wait for completion of Job B.
Like this D is dependent on B so after completion of Job B, immediately Job D will start.

Currently I am using multithreading concept to run the whole process according to seq_num. But I want desirable scenario which is not depends on seq_num. How can wait the dependent process until its parent process completed?
I am sharing my code also. Please let me know where I need to change code to get desirable scenario. Please let me know if you need more information.

Code:

```
def parallel_Execution():
    
    logging.info("parallel_Execution..................[started]")
    par_temp_loc = '/medaff/Temp/'

    '''Reading the metadata file and creating as a dataframe'''
    df = pd.read_csv(par_temp_loc+'metadata_file_imedical.txt', delimiter='|',error_bad_lines=False)
    uni_master_job = df['Master Job Name'].unique().tolist()
    print(uni_master_job)

    '''getting unique execution sequence'''
    logging.info("Getting the unique Execution Sequence Number!")
    unique_exec_seq = df['Execution Sequence'].unique().tolist()
    unique_exec_seq.sort()
    print(unique_exec_seq)
    num_unique_seq = len(unique_exec_seq)
    logging.info("Total Number of unique sequence Number : %2d" %(num_unique_seq))

    
    p2 = ThreadWithReturnValue(target = partial(parallel_temp2, unique_exec_seq, df ))
    p2.start()

    r2 = p2.join()
    print(r2)

    #r1 = r1.append(r2)
    mail_df(r2)

'''Parallel Processing Function'''
def parallel_temp2(unique_exec_seq, df):
    list_df = []
    df_main4 = pd.DataFrame()
    for exec_seq in unique_exec_seq:
        seq_num = exec_seq
        temp_df = df[df['Execution Sequence'] == exec_seq].copy()
        unique_master_job = temp_df['Master Job Name'].unique().tolist()
        print(unique_master_job)
        #logging.info("%s Master Job Started." %(unique_master_job))

        if(len(unique_master_job)>0):
                    
            num_processes = len(unique_master_job)
            pool = ThreadPool(processes=num_processes)
            result1 = pool.map(partial(parallel_view_creation, exec_seq, temp_df), unique_master_job)
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
            df_main = pd.DataFrame(result1)
            #print("printing df_main")
            #print(df_main)
                
            for m_job in df_main.master_job.unique():
                temp_df1 = df_main[df_main['master_job'] == m_job]
                status = temp_df1.status.unique()[0]
                if(status == 0):
                    unique_master_job.remove(m_job)

            pool = ThreadPool(processes=num_processes)
            result2 = pool.map(partial(parallel_build_query, exec_seq, temp_df), unique_master_job)
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
            if(result2):                
                df_main2 = pd.DataFrame(result2)

            df_main3 = pd.concat([df_main,df_main2], sort = False)
            status_df_list = df_main3['status'].unique().tolist()
            print(status_df_list)
            if(0 in status_df_list):
                break
        if(0 in status_df_list):
            break
        else:
            df_main4 = df_main4.append(df_main3)
    if(0 in status_df_list):
        df_main4 = df_main4.append(df_main3)
                
    return df_main4
```

Code Explanation:

First I am reading the metadata file which contain all the information about job and seq_num.
Then I am taking the unique job and unique seq_num.
passing into ThreadWithReturnValue function.

In Parallel_temp2 function based on the seq_num I am triggering the jobs.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Is the number of jobs fixed or they can vary? If you are dealing with always 4 jobs you could spawn 4 threads and use [conditions](https://fburl.com/4i5pb7p3) to check which one can proceed with processing. If the number of jobs varies this can get more complex

Comment: Hi @urban. This is just example which I have written. I am working on 50 jobs this time.

Comment: @urban, Could you please help me to implement below logic on my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential way is:

- Extend thread to create your custom Thread object which is aware of its dependencies (and can also store a result)
- In the run of each of these threads (that I call "Jobs") wait for all dependent jobs to finish. I do this by having an Event in each Job.
- When a Job is done, flag/set the `finished` event

Minimal code:

```
import time
from random import randint
from threading import Thread, Event

class Job(Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, target, args=(), deps=None):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.result = None
        self.deps = deps
        self.target = target
        self.args = args
        self.finished = Event()

    def run(self):
        print(f"{self.name} waiting")
        # Wait for all dependent jobs to finish
        if self.deps:
            for dep in self.deps:
                dep.finished.wait()

        print(f"{self.name} running!")

        # Now we can start
        self.result = self.target(self.deps, *self.args)

        # Flag this job as done
        self.finished.set()
        print(f"{self.name} done")


def sleep_random_time(deps, *args):
    """
    Sleep random time and return the time slept

    Args:
        deps: a list of (direct) dependencies
    """
    if deps:
        for dep in deps:
            print(f"  Result of dependency {dep.name}={dep.result}")
    t = randint(2,20)
    time.sleep(t)
    return t


def main():
    # Create our jobs. I am almost certain this can be done smarter with some
    # sort of tree but it highly depends on how/where you get your jobs
    jobs = []
    jobs.append(Job("A", sleep_random_time))
    jobs.append(Job("B", sleep_random_time))
    jobs.append(Job("C", sleep_random_time, deps=[jobs[0]]))
    jobs.append(Job("D", sleep_random_time, deps=[jobs[1]]))
    jobs.append(Job("E", sleep_random_time, deps=[jobs[1], jobs[2]]))

    for j in jobs:
        j.start()
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
$ python3 ~/tmp/test.py
A waiting
A running!
B waiting
C waiting
D waiting
E waiting
B running!
A done
C running!
  Result of dependency A=18
B done
D running!
  Result of dependency B=18
D done
C done
E running!
  Result of dependency B=18
  Result of dependency C=20
E done
```

Notes:

- Note that there is no threadpool here. This means that *all* thread run simultaneously and there is no way to limit the number of threads. However, lots of these threads will go to sleep right-away. This might be acceptable since you mentioned that you have 50ish jobs. If the number of jobs increases to thousands, a different implementation might be needed
- Looking at the jobs, I see a dependency tree. I am sure we can express the deps as a tree where the root node is your main and the leaf nodes are the jobs with no dependencies

---

#### Threadpool-based solution

With slight modification of the Job definition:

- Create a threadpool
- Keep on looping jobs and submitting them to the pool, only if they can start
- Jobs no longer need to be threads, they are just data containers

```
import time
from random import randint
from threading import Thread, Event
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


class Job:
    def __init__(self, name, target, args=(), deps=None):
        self.result = None
        self.name = name
        self.deps = deps
        self.target = target
        self.args = args
        self.finished = Event()

    def can_run(self):
        if not self.deps:
            return True

        for dep in self.deps:
            if not dep.finished.is_set():
                return False

        return True

    def run(self):
        print(f"{self.name} running!")

        # Now we can start
        self.result = self.target(self.deps, *self.args)

        # Flag this job as done
        self.finished.set()
        print(f"{self.name} done")


def sleep_random_time(deps, *args):
    """
    Sleep random time and return the time slept

    Args:
        deps: a list of (direct) dependencies
    """
    if deps:
        for dep in deps:
            print(f"  Result of dependency {dep.name}={dep.result}")
    t = randint(2,20)
    time.sleep(t)
    return t


def main():
    # Create our jobs. I am almost certain this can be done smarter with some
    # sort of tree but it highly depends on how/where you get your jobs
    jobs = []
    jobs.append(Job("A", sleep_random_time))
    jobs.append(Job("B", sleep_random_time))
    jobs.append(Job("C", sleep_random_time, deps=[jobs[0]]))
    jobs.append(Job("D", sleep_random_time, deps=[jobs[1]]))
    jobs.append(Job("E", sleep_random_time, deps=[jobs[1], jobs[2]]))

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as pool:
        while jobs:
            for j in jobs:
                if j.can_run():
                    pool.submit(j.run)
                    jobs.remove(j)
                    # break this for loop since we changed the list we are
                    # iterating
                    break
            time.sleep(0.2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
$ python3 ~/tmp/test.py
A running!
B running!
A done
C running!
  Result of dependency A=8
C done
B done
D running!
  Result of dependency B=12
E running!
  Result of dependency B=12
  Result of dependency C=4
D done
E done
```

Comment: Thank you for great help and suggestion. Can you please look into my code also and suggest me what the changes need to do to get desirable output? I am not much aware of multithreading concept. So please help me.

Comment: First I am reading metadata file and then doing all the operation but I am iterating the for loop based on seq_num. Can you please tell me Where I do changes?

Comment: Your answer and suggestion is really appreciating.

Comment: Hi.. Please help me!!

Comment: Hi @urban.. Can you please help me?